# Get an actual plan for a stored function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-execution-plan

I want to get an execution plan for my scalar function because it differs from one when I'm only running a function body. I was in same situation some time ago, and I solved it by defragmenting indices (function didn't use fragmented indices because of high fragmentation, but pure query did). But now i have <0.1% fragmentation.

I can get proper estimate execution plan, but when I want to get an actual plan, 
I get almost nothing.

So here I get only useless outer query plan, but don't see what's happening in function.

Can it be fixed?

---

Estimated execution plan:

```
<ParameterList>
  <ColumnReference Column="@DateTo" ParameterCompiledValue="NULL" />
  <ColumnReference Column="@DateFrom" ParameterCompiledValue="NULL" />
  <ColumnReference Column="@ServerID" ParameterCompiledValue="NULL" />
  <ColumnReference Column="@ResourceTypeID" ParameterCompiledValue="NULL" />
</ParameterList>
```

---

I found an actual execution plan for the function (thanks to Sql Server Profiler)

Actual plan for pure query (fast):
[image]
function (slow):
[image]

this function is just taking some XML field from table and join them into one big XML file:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetErrorXML]
(   
    @DateFrom datetime,     
    @DateTo datetime,       
    @ResourceTypeID bigint,  
    @ServerID int           
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @ErrorDescription VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @ErrorDescription = '<root>';
    WITH CTE AS
    (   

        SELECT 
            d.GeneratedOnUtc,
            ErrorDescription = cast(d.Data as nvarchar(max))
        FROM dbo.AgentData d
          INNER JOIN dbo.Agent a ON a.CheckID = d.CheckID
          INNER JOIN dbo.Server s ON a.ServerID = s.ID
        WHERE d.EventType = 'Result' AND
              a.ResourceTypeID & @ResourceTypeID > 0 AND
              s.ID = @ServerID AND
              d.GeneratedOnUtc between @DateFrom AND @DateTo AND
              d.Result = 0                            
    )
    SELECT @ErrorDescription = @ErrorDescription + cte.ErrorDescription
    FROM CTE    
    ORDER BY cte.GeneratedOnUtc ASC

    RETURN(@ErrorDescription + '</root>')
END
```

Comment: Probably parameter sniffing. You could likely pull the plan from the cache and see what parameters it was compiled with and then reproduce the issue by putting the logic in a stored procedure and executing it first with those param values and then secondly with the param values shown in your question.

Comment: You could also retrieve the actual plan with profiler or extended events. The reason for this behaviour is discussed here http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29749/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith please, can you explain it in detail?

Comment: In the estimated plan can you view it as XML and see the `ParameterCompiledValue`s?

Comment: Yep, with the extra info looks like a parameter sniffing issue. You could try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: Your best bet would be to get rid of the scalar function. They are notoriously poor performers.

Comment: @SeanLange well, maybe, but i don't know any alternative except inline query that makes query unreadable. But if you have any suggestions I'm ready to listen very carefully (no irony)

Comment: I don't know what your scalar function does so I can't really offer much in the way of details. Maybe an inline table valued function would work? Maybe just using an additional query with APPLY? Without more details it is hard to know what to suggest.

Comment: That is a absolutely perfect candidate for an inline table valued function.

Comment: Here is a great article on this very topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/ You will probably need to tweak your query a bit to use FOR XML since you are trying to generate XML data. I don't know what your tables are like or what your output should be but it shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, answer for my initial question: you can use `SQL Server Profiler` and profile your database and get plans for all executing queries, just toggle a chechbox in `new trace` settings.